# How to return value from function onResponse of Retrofit and call it in other procedure?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm new with retrofit and I want to make my getData list to save value from onResponse body list and call it in different procedure. What is the easiest way to do that?
I have been try it, data has been show in onResponse but when I want to use it in different procedure the value getData list is still null

my onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // getDataSeason();
    listSeason=new ArrayList<>();
    progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.setMessage("Loading. . .");
    progress.show();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(getURL.GetMyURL())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    SeasonAPI api = retrofit.create(SeasonAPI.class);

    Call<SeasonList> call = api.getAllSeason();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<SeasonList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SeasonList> call, Response<SeasonList> response) {
            progress.dismiss();
            response.body();
            for(int i=0;i<response.body().getResult().size();i++){
                getData.add(i,response.body().getResult().get(i));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SeasonList> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            progress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Network Connection Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });}
```

String temp

My getData List

```
public class FragmentPromo extends Fragment {

public List<Season> getData;
```

my SeasonList

```
public class SeasonList {
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private Integer value;
@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private List<Season> result = null;

public Integer getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Integer value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public List<Season> getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(List<Season> result) {
    this.result = result;
}}
```

Its null when i want to show getData value in oncreateView

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_promo,container,false);
    //Set date in Text View
    txtDate=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtDateTime);
    txtDate.setText(currendtDateTimeString);

    myRecycleView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.season_view);
    recycleViewAdapterSeason =new RecycleViewAdapterSeason(getContext(),listSeason);
    myRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    myRecycleView.setAdapter(recycleViewAdapterSeason);
    getDataSeason();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getData.get(0).getNamaSeason(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return view;
}
```

Comment: where is the your model class or SeasonList ?

Comment: be specific, which value is **null**? share the code where it is null

Comment: I already update it

Comment: Can you update the code, which sets the `listSeason`?

Answer (score 0):

- First , when dealing with Retrofit it's better to make a **Singleton** class you can read about this design pattern and how it's very helpful when it comes to memory management
- Second , at **onResponse()** why you are calling response.body() before the loop and not using it ?
- You are getting a null pointer exception because you want to use a list without initializing it
- All what you have to do is making an object from SesaonList class and assign it's value to your response , **getData** will be assigned by getting  list of season from the object by calling **getResult** , this should work

`@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SeasonList>call,Response<SeasonList>response){
            progress.dismiss();
            Seasonlist seasonlist = response.body();
            getData = seasonlist.getResult();
}`